# Prime ideals of $S^{-1}\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ for two sets S

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I want to describe the prime ideals of $S^{-1}\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$, where S is a multiplicative set, where

1. $S:=\{X^kY^l\mid k,l \in \mathbb{N}\}$
2. $S:=\{fg \mid 0 \neq f\in\mathbb{C}[X], 0\neq g\in \mathbb{C}[Y]\}$.

I already know that the prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ are $(0)$, $(p)$ with p an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ and $(X-a, Y-b)$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$. I also know that the prime ideals of $S^{-1}\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ are in bijective correspondence to the prime ideals in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ that don't intersect with $S$.
What my problem is: If I take a prime ideal $(X-a)$, with $S$ given in 1), then isn't $S$ always contained in $(X-a)$?
Is there a way how you can always approach such a task?